# Validate an input field after select

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need some help with validating an input field that has a minimum value after selecting a valuta dropdown list.

Here is the part of the form:

```
<div class="row">
    <header class="margin-bottom-20">I hereby guarantee payment up to:</header>
    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">Amount
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="7500">
        </label>
    </section>

    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="select">Valuta
            <select name="valuta" id="valuta" onChange="Choice();">
                <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            </select>
            <i></i>
        </label>
    </section>                                          
</div>
```

After selecting the valuta it has a pre filled minimum price. Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#valuta').change(function(){
        console.log("test");
        var amount = this.value;
        var str = "";

        switch(amount){
            case "SEK":
                str = "2500";
                break;
            case "EUR":
                str = "250";
                break;
        }
        $("#amount").val(str);
    });
</script>
```

Now comes the tricky part (at least for me). I need to validate the input field after the selected valuta. I use jQuery validate, but I don't know how I can combine the above jQuery with the validation.

```
        // Validation
        $("#my-form").validate({
            // Rules for form validation
            rules:
            {
                amount:
                {
                    required: true,
                    min: 2500 (When SEK is selected)
                    min 250 (When EUR is selected)
                },
```

Comment: Applu your initial validation to all fields as normally we do. Then on change of select value, you can add/remove dynamic jquery validation https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/ once go through this link

Comment: @Danny , it is easy as per above comment apply initial validation to all fields and then on change you can validate input like $('#amount').valid(). you can use like if($('amount').valid()){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own custom validation method to jQuery.

```
    $.validator.addMethod('minRule', function (value, el, param) {
        if($('#valuta').val() == "SEK")
           return value > 2500;
        if($('#valuta').val() == "EUR")
           return value > 250;
    },"Please provide enter correct amount"); // Message added
```

Usage:

```
amount: {
    required: true,
    minRule: 0,
    number: true
}
```

Comment: This didn't do the trick either. It gives a validation error on the dropdown menu: Warning: No message defined for amount

Answer (score 0):

I almost got it to work with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#valuta').change(function(){
        console.log("test");
        var amount = this.value;
        var str = "";

        switch(amount){
            case "SEK":
                str = "2500";
                break;
            case "EUR":
                str = "250";
                break;
        }
        if ($('#valuta').val() == 'SEK') {
            $('#amount').val("2500");
            $('#amount').attr("min", 2500);
        } else if($('#valuta').val() == 'EUR') {
            $('#amount').val("250");
            $('#amount').attr("min", 250);
        }

        $("#amount").val(str);


    });
</script>
```

Problem now is, because it's preselected to SEK with a value on the input field of 2500, the validation doesn't work. I can change the amount to 1 and that's a valid input, however it has to be 2500 and above.
I works when I change it to EUR and change the amount below 250 and when I change it again to SEK and change the amount below 2500.

How can I validate the preselected value when someone change it to 1?

Answer (score 0):

throw away jquery validate for this case only. its can make you confuse. because you still learn jquery.

i edit your code as possible as i can.

here

```
<div class="row">
    <header class="margin-bottom-20">I hereby guarantee payment up to:</header>
    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">Amount
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="7500" required>
        </label>
    </section>

    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="select">Valuta
            <select name="valuta" id="valuta" >
             <option value="">pick valuta</option>
                <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            </select>
            <i></i>
        </label>
    </section>                                          
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#valuta').change(function(){
        var valuta = $(this).val();
var amount = $('#amount').val();

        switch(valuta){
            case "SEK":
                if(amount<2500) amount=2500;
                break;
            case "EUR":
                if(amount<250) amount=250;
                break;
        }
        $("#amount").val(amount);
    });
});
</script>
```